# Finding the bigger of $\cos^2(b)$ or $\sin^2(a+b)$ when $2\tan(a)\tan(b)=1$ and $a+b<\pi/2$

Tags: trigonometry

Question:

> It is given that: $$2\tan(a)\tan(b)=1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad a+b<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
> Then which is bigger: $\cos^2(b)$ or $\sin^2(a+b)$?

So basically for a condition given in a question to be proved I have to prove this that $\cos^2(b) ≤ \sin^2(a+b)$ with the given information.

First thing I thought that as all angles are smaller than $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

So if $b \geq \frac{\pi}{4}$ then $\sin(a+b)$ will be greater than $\cos(b)$ for sure.

But if $b<\frac{\pi}{4}$ then $\cos(b)>\sin(b)$. if I add something in $b$ without giving a range I couldn't say that $\sin(a+b)$ will be greater than $\cos(b)$.

So for a general I can say that

> If $a+b \geq \frac{\pi}{2}-b$ or $a+2b≥\frac{\pi}{2}$ then $\cos(b)$ can be smaller than or equal to $\sin(a+b)$.

But after it I can't think much to deduce and use given information I made from the question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: How about checking when $\cos(b) = \sin(a+b)$? You have two variables i.e. $a$ and $b$ and two equations i.e. $2\tan(a)\tan(b) =1$ and $\cos(b) = \sin(a+b)$. If you prove that there is no solution (or there is a proper unique one) then, together with your argument above you are done.

Comment: Well that's plausible but cos(b)=sin(a+b) doesn't hold always it's just a possibility but for the more correct answer I have to prove that cos(b)≤sin(a+b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2\tan a\tan b =1$ implies $\sin a \sin b =\cos(a+b)$.

So
$\sin^2 (a+b)=1-\cos^2 (a+b)=1-\sin^2 a \sin^2 b \geq 1-\sin^2 b = \cos^2 b$.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I am not quite able to understand what you just did there 

Comment: I multiplied the original equation by cos a cos b and used the formula for cos(a+b). Then the rest uses the Pythagorean identity for cos and sin

Comment: Ok I got it now thanks but it would be great if you write it in like systematic order for others to understand.I mean it's in order but like more understandable

Comment: Hey can you tell how you were able to tell that 1-sin²a•sin²b ≥ 1-sin²b

Comment: Sure. As the $\sin^2 a $ is less than or equal to 1, $\sin^2 a \sin^2 b $ is less than or equal to $\sin^2 b$. This is the part which gives an inequality.

Comment: Got it  now I understand 

Answer (score 2):

Given
$$
2\tan{a} \tan{b} = 1
$$

I will seek to find $\sin(a+b)^2$ in terms of $\cos({b})^2$

Through double angle formulas and some algebraic manipulation:

$$
\sin(a+b)^2 = (\sin{a} \cos{b} + \sin{b} \cos{a})^2 \\
= \sin{a}^2 \cos{b}^2 + 2 \sin{a} \cos{b} \sin{b} \cos{a} + \sin{b}^2 \cos{a}^2 \\
= \sin{a}^2 \cos{b}^2 + 2 \frac{\sin{a} \sin{b}}{\cos{a} \cos{b}} \cos{a}^2 \cos{b}^2  + \sin{b}^2 \cos{a}^2 \\
= \sin{a}^2 \cos{b}^2 + 1 \times \cos{a}^2 \cos{b}^2 + \sin{b}^2 \cos{a}^2 \\
= \sin{a}^2 \cos{b}^2 + \cos{a}^2 \cos{b}^2 + \sin{b}^2 \cos{a}^2
$$

By taking $\cos({b})^2$ as a common factor:
$$
\sin(a+b)^2 = \cos({b})^2 (\sin({a})^2 + \cos({a})^2) + \sin({b})^2 \cos({a})^2 \\
\sin(a+b)^2 = \cos({b})^2 + \sin({b})^2 \cos({a})^2
$$

Now this clearly shows that $\sin(a+b)^2$ will always be bigger than $\cos({b})^2$.

I can't find a way to proof that it might *equal* it, and strangely enough I never used $a+b < \frac{\pi}{2}$ except for verifying my solution numerically on my trusty casio, or maybe this makes sure the tangent terms are not infinity I really don't know, But I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for solving my question well I should have certainly see that I could have made 2tan(a)tan(b) but was stuck. And yeah the condition a+b<π/2 was just something I noticed and thought it might be useful but well it wasn't needed actually it was a part of solving a particular situation which happens to be the case that a+b<π/2

Comment: And yeah for it to be equal was certainly just a condition I thought if possible could also result to the ending result but certainly with all the given condition it might not be possible I guess

Answer (score 0):

*This answer might be for lack of proper tools a bit confusing to look at (and its not deductive, but i think shows the point okay-ish).*

I have graphed your two constraints $2\tan(a)\tan(b)=1$ and $a+b<\frac{\pi}{2}$ by taking $a=x$ and $b=y$. This comes out to [td_c] (in a top down view for clarity).

I have then taken your two functions to compare and put them as $z=\cos^2(y)$ and $z=\sin^2(x+y)$. This results in [td_f] in the same top-down and [a_f] in an angled way. Your already deduced boundaries involving $\frac{\pi}{4}$ seem to hold, but it also seems that beyond that, one function sometimes is strictly bigger than the other and the other way around. Again, this is not deductive, but might show why a deductive proof might be impossible.

[td_c]: [Top-Down view of constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgMgQ.png)

[td_f]: [Top-Down view of inserted functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oGMn.png)

[a_f]: [Angled view of inserted functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LGzA.png)